# How to make Chrome Print To PDF obey --window-size

Tags: windows, command-line, google-chrome, pdf

I am struggling with changing the `--window-size` when saving to PDF via Chrome (via command line).

The following executes perfectly

> chrome --headless --disable-gpu --window-size=1400,650 --print-to-pdf=C:\Users\MyName\Documents\myTestFile.pdf https://superuser.com

If I change the `--window-size` to `--window-size=400,650` (note it changed from 1400 to 400) it has no impact

Each time, the PDF looks like

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Why can't I change the width and height?

**edit** my monitor screen solution is 3k

Comment: What is your screen size, is it smaller than 1400?